# PDO and prepared statements (In PHP)

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I am in the process of going through all my SQL statements and updating them to have prepared statements.  This is working fine, however I realised that I wasn't preparing ALL my variables, just the ones in the WHERE statement.  So I had this PHP code:

```
$results = $this->PDOSelect("SELECT `hash` FROM {$db}.{$table} WHERE `hash`='{$hash}';",true);
```

Which works fine and returns the right result set, of course.  But then I wanted to update it and prepare the statement, as I have done others.  Then I realised that not only did I have to put `:hash` in the WHERE clause, but I have two other variables as well for the database.

So I tried the following (which doesnt look right to me):

```
$this->authPrepared = array("database" => $db, "table" => $table, "hash" => $hash);
$results = $this->PDOSelect("SELECT `hash` FROM :database.:table WHERE `hash`=:hash;",true);
```

And it's not returning anything, as expected.  How can I prepare this statement? Can I only prepare variables that are in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Could you try it by making a new varibale that contains the value of `:database.:table`, e.g. database.table1 and insert this one instead of `:database.:table`?

Comment: ...Can it be done in MYSQLi then?

Comment: No. Pay specific attention to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990488/476